# SUDO - Error with sudoers_audit plugin

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, sudo, sudoers

I have one problem with sudo. When I run sudo in regular account I get:

```bsh
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Permission denied
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

But I commented the line where was written `Plugin audit` in /etc/sudo.conf. And here is my /etc/sudoers:

```bsh
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
running ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
running ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Note that sudo works without problem in root account but only fails at regular account(regular account is `running` here.)

How can I solve this??

Comment: I think (guess) it can be a problem with a [setresuid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setresuid.2.html) call in your script. See the EPERM error on the man page... I don't know if there is a way to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

The error `sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Permission denied` occurs when the process/ user lacks the  `CAP_SETUID` capability. The man page `setresuid(2)` ([Link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setresuid.2.html)) mentions this as being required.

The lack of this capability can stem from multiple sources, like a restricted cgroup or systemd unit. Without more information on your user account/ execution context a concrete answer can't be given here.

You could try to track down your current capabilities by  inspecting one of your own processes with `grep Cap /proc/<pid>/status`. This should show your all enabled capabilities.

For systemd units the `CapabilityBoundingSet` and related options are responsible for handling capabilities. In this case you should take a look at the unit file and/ or relate process.

Some capabilities can also be bound to the user as discussed [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user).

PS: This answer is most likely to late. However, I encountered this recently and wanted to share the solution for the next person stumbling across this question.

Comment: Yes, answer was way more late but let's hope that it will help next person who faces with it. Thanks for your answer.